# syslog-ng - Passing FILENAME from client to server when using wildcard_file

Tags: error-logging, syslog-ng

I am using syslog-ng, to remote log the application logs of multiple containers of the same image. I am using the source config as below.

```
source s_wild { wildcard-file(
    base-dir("/var/myapp/logs")
    filename-pattern("*")
    recursive(no)
    flags(no-parse)
    follow-freq(1)
); };
```

When I am using the logging in the local machine (for testing purposes), using the MACRO, ${FILE_NAME}, it works. But the filename is not being passed on, over network when testing with the remote server.

```
Aug  3 19:39:46 46fc878e92cf syslog-ng[2320]: Error opening file for writing; filename='', error='Is a directory (21)'
```

There are around 20-25 files and am looking for auto mapping of the filenames in both client and server side. Is it possible. Not sure how the wildcard_file maps to remote server. Logically it may not be possible. Still wondering on a solution.

I am wondering whether I can avoid manual 1-1 mapping by defining multiple source and destination or using log_prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$FILE_NAME` macro works only if syslog-ng receives messages from a file or a wildcard-file source and it does not work over `network()`. A couple of options you have here to pass file names over network are:

1. Use the structured-data section of a [RFC 5424](https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/using-rfc5424-syslog-protocol-plain-tcp-rsyslog-syslog-ng) syslog message
2. Use [template()](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/57#TOPIC-956603) with [json-parser()](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/release-notes/the-json-parser-the-json-parser) to send messages from client-side and parse them on server side
3. Use [ewmm()](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/release-notes/enterprise-wide-message-model-ewmm) (Enterprise-wide message model) which supports delivery of structured messages

In the first method, sending the RFC5424-formatted (IETF-syslog) messages allows you to set the `FILE_NAME` in the [SDATA](https://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.18/administration-guide/62#TOPIC-1044123) field. Use the `syslog()` on the source and destination side instead of `network()` to send the messages using IETF syslog protocol. The source file wildcard can be defined like [this](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/release-notes/wildcard-file-source-options). The whole configuration would be something like below:

**syslog-ng client side**

```
source s_wild {
        wildcard-file(
                base-dir("/var/log_syslog")
                filename-pattern("*")
                recursive(no)
                follow-freq(1)
                );

};

rewrite r_set_filename{
    set(
        "$FILE_NAME",
         value(".SDATA.file@18372.4.name")
        );
};

rewrite r_use_basename {
  subst(
        "/var/log_syslog/",
        "",
        value(".SDATA.file@18372.4.name")
        type("string")
        flags("prefix")
       );
};

destination d_container_logs {
        syslog(
              "192.168.10.48"
               transport("tcp")
               port(5141)
        );
};

log {source(s_wild); rewrite(r_set_filename); rewrite(r_use_basename); destination(d_container_logs);};
```

The `r_set_filename` gets the absolute path of file and we chop-off the path bit and retains only the filename using `r_use_basename`

**syslog-ng server side**

```
source s_network {
        syslog(
        transport("tcp")
        port(5141)
        keep_hostname(yes)
        );
};


destination d_container_logs {
    file(
        "/var/sys_log/${.SDATA.file@18372.4.name}"
        create_dirs(yes)
        );
};

log {source(s_network); destination(d_container_logs);};
```

Comment: It worked perfrectly. Thanks @tuxway. Didn't know that you can use syslog itself instead of network in RFC 5424.